# How to save New Record using mvvm wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i am new in wpf and mvvm i tried to learn to use it  first i successes to show a list of my employee class very good but when i want to add a new one ( means a new employee ) it saves an new empty record in the database , i do not know how to get the value from the textboxs. i searched a lot but cannot reach what's my problem , so can i get any help here is my code

```
MY MODEL CLASS
public class Employees 
{

    #region Employee Members

    int _id;
    string _firstname;
    string _address;
    string _lastname;
    string _language;
    string _dob;
    string _nationality;
    string _gender;


    #endregion

    #region Members Properties

    Notify.NotifyUIBase n = new Notify.NotifyUIBase();

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this._firstname; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._firstname)
            {
                this._firstname = value;
                n.RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }

        }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
            n.RaisePropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set
        {
            _lastname = value;
            n.RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    public string Language
    {
        get { return _language; }
        set
        {
            _language = value;
            n.RaisePropertyChanged("Language");
        }
    }

    public string DOB
    {
        get { return _dob; }
        set
        {
            _dob = (value).ToString();
            n.RaisePropertyChanged("DOB");
        }
    }

    public string Nationality
    {
        get { return _nationality; }
        set
        {
            _nationality = value;
            n.RaisePropertyChanged("Nationality");
        }
    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get { return _gender; }
        set
        {
            _gender = value;
            n.RaisePropertyChanged("Gender");
        }
    }

    #endregion

}

MY NOTIFY CLASS  
public class NotifyUIBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

MY VIEWMODEL
    public class EditaEmployeesViewModel
    {
        #region Constructor

        public EditaEmployeesViewModel()
        {
            // intiales commands 
            NewEmployeeButton = new RelayCommand(OpenNewEmployee);
            UpdateEmployeeButton = new RelayCommand(UpdateEmployee);
            DeleteEmployeeButton = new RelayCommand(DeleteEmployee);

            SaveNewEmployeeButton = new RelayCommand(SaveNewEmployee);

        }

        #endregion

        #region Variables

        public RelayCommand NewEmployeeButton { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand UpdateEmployeeButton { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand DeleteEmployeeButton { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand SaveNewEmployeeButton { get; set; }

        #endregion



        #region Command Methods

        void OpenNewEmployee(object parameter)
        {
            View.AddUpdateEmployee aue = new View.AddUpdateEmployee();
            aue.Show();
        }

        void UpdateEmployee(object parameter)
        {

        }

        void DeleteEmployee(object parameter)
        {

        }

        void SaveNewEmployee(object parameter)
        {

       DataAccess.EmplyeeDatabaseLayer.InsertEmployee(** what to pass here 
       to the insert sql ***);

        }
        #endregion

        #region get Employee List

        public ObservableCollection<Model.Employees> EmployeeList
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<Model.Employees> List = new ObservableCollection<Model.Employees>(DataAccess.EmplyeeDatabaseLayer.GetEmployeeFromDataBase());
                return List;
            }
        }
        #endregion

MY DATABASE CLASS
public class EmplyeeDatabaseLayer
{
    public static List<Model.Employees> GetEmployeeFromDataBase()
    {
        string sql = "select * from Employees";

        DataTable dt = DBConnections.SelectQuery(sql);
        var Employee = new List<Model.Employees>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var obj = new Model.Employees()
            {
                ID = (int)row["id"],
                FirstName = (string)row["FirstName"],
                LastName = (string)row["LastName"],
                DOB = (string)row["DOB"],
                Gender = (string)row["Gender"],
                Nationality = (string)row["Nationality"],
                Language = ((string)row["Language"]),
                Address = (string)row["Address"]
            };
            Employee.Add(obj);
        }
        return Employee;
    }

    internal static void InsertEmployee(Model.Employees employee)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "insert into Employees ([FirstName],[LastName],[Gender],[DOB],[Language],[Nationality],[Address]) values ";
            sql += "('" + employee.FirstName + "','" + employee.LastName + "','" + employee.Gender + "',";
            sql += "'" + employee.DOB + "','" + employee.Language + "','" + employee.Nationality + "'";
            sql += ",'" + employee.Address + "')";
            DBConnections.InserQuery(sql);

            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully.");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    internal static void UpdateEmployee(Model.Employees employee)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "Update Employees set [FirstName]='" + employee.FirstName + "',[LastName]='" + employee.LastName + "',";
            sql += "[Gender] ='" + employee.Gender + "',[DOB]='" + employee.DOB + "',[Language]='" + employee.Language + "',";
            sql += "[Nationality]='" + employee.Nationality + "',[Address]='" + employee.Address + "' where [ID]='" + employee.ID + "'";

            DBConnections.UpdateQuery(sql);

            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully.");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    internal static void DeleteEmployee(Model.Employees employee)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "Delete * from Employees where ID='" + employee.ID + "'";

            DBConnections.DeleteQuery(sql);

            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted Successfully.");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}


MY VIEW ( SHOW EMPLOYEES LIST)

<Window x:Class="EditaWPF01.NewTest.View.EmployeePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EditaWPF01.NewTest.View"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EditaWPF01.NewTest.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Employees" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:EditaEmployeesViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Employees List" Margin="5">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ToolBarTray >
                <ToolBar >
                    <Button  x:Name="tlNewGas" ToolTip="New Gas" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" 
                             Command="{Binding NewEmployeeButton}">
                        <Image Source=".\Pics\File_20px.png" />
                    </Button>
                    <Separator/>
                    <Button  x:Name="tlUpdateGas" ToolTip="Update Gas" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" 
                             Command="{Binding UpdateEmployeeButton}">
                        <Image Source=".\Pics\Edit File_20px.png"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Separator/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnDelete" ToolTip="Delete Gas" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" 
                            Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteEmployeeButton}"/>


                </ToolBar>
            </ToolBarTray>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="F.Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="L.Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DOB" Binding="{Binding DOB}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nationality" Binding="{Binding Nationality}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language" Binding="{Binding Language}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

```
MY FORM TO ADD NEW EMPLOYEE
<Window x:Class="EditaWPF01.NewTest.View.AddUpdateEmployee"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EditaWPF01.NewTest.View"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EditaWPF01.NewTest.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Add/Update Employee" Height="450" Width="500" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:EditaEmployeesViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToolBarTray Background="Orange">
        <ToolBar Background="Orange">
            <Button  x:Name="tlNewGas" ToolTip="New Gas" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     Padding="0" Content="Save" Height="27" Command="{Binding SaveNewEmployeeButton}"/>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <TextBlock Text="First Name :" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Last Name :" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Address :" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Text="{Binding Address, BindingGroupName=Group1, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="DOB :" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Text="{Binding DOB, BindingGroupName=Group1, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Language :" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Text="{Binding Language, BindingGroupName=Group1, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Nationality :" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Text="{Binding Nationality, BindingGroupName=Group1, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Gender :" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Text="{Binding Gender, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

i left the command of the saveNewEmployee empty , i can not know how to get it done

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may lie at `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`. Your source is never updated until you explicitly update it.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-control-when-the-textbox-text-updates-the-source